# Java excel grouping data

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-poi

How do I group the data that I have in excel and output each section of grouped data to individual excel sheets?

My code below does the following:
1) Gets all the data from and excel sheet (.xlsx), displays it.
2) Outputs the same data to another path with a name.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated

```
package javaapplication8;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class JavaApplication8 {
private static String path = "";


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame); // parentComponent must a component like JFrame, JDialog...
    if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();

    }

    try {

FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(path));

//Get the workbook instance for XLS file
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

//Get first sheet from the workbook
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

//Iterate through each rows from first sheet
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();

    //For each row, iterate through each columns
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
    while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

        switch(cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
file.close();
FileOutputStream out =
    new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\test.xlsx"));
workbook.write(out);
out.close();

} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

If copied the above code should work for any .xlsx file

The data sample i am trying to group is:

```
EPPACC      Cname       AbarDate    CTermDat    MDiscDat
A4041222    Sihlaba     2011/09/16  2013/09/15  2012/11/20
A4041231    Gwavu       2011/09/26  2013/09/26  2012/11/22
A4041260    Lin         2011/11/21  2013/11/20  2012/11/29
A4041260    Lin         2011/09/16  2013/09/15  2012/11/29
A4041281    Sharma      2011/09/16  2013/09/15  2013/01/21
A4041336    Nkwankwana  2011/09/16  2013/09/15  2013/01/21
A4041336    Nkwankwana  2011/09/16  2013/09/15  2013/01/21
A4041420    Gqozo       2011/09/22  2013/09/21  2012/07/18
A4041420    Gqozo       2011/09/22  2013/09/21  2012/07/20
A4041494    Henneberry  2011/09/21  2013/09/20  2013/01/21
A4041522    Monepya     2011/09/16  2013/09/15  2013/01/21
A4041600    Vezi        2011/09/16  2013/09/15  2012/12/13
A4041640    Cupido      2011/09/27  2013/09/26  2012/09/25
A4041640    Cupido      2011/09/26  2013/09/25  2012/11/27
A4041644    Mfingwana   2011/09/27  2013/09/26  2013/01/21
A4041644    Mfingwana   2011/09/27  2013/09/27  2013/01/21
A4041665    Mafura      2011/09/29  2013/09/28  2012/12/13
A4041770    Mlangeni    2011/09/17  2013/09/16  2012/10/12
A4041965    Vukeya      2011/09/17  2013/09/17  2012/11/22
A4042005    Tayerera    2011/09/17  2013/09/16  2012/11/27
A4042005    Tayerera    2011/11/11  2013/11/10  2012/11/27
A4042005    Tayerera    2011/11/11  2013/11/10  2012/11/27
A4042005    Tayerera    2011/09/17  2013/09/16  2012/11/27
A4042029    Wallace     2011/09/17  2013/09/16  2013/01/21
A4042188    Khoza       2011/10/04  2013/10/04  2012/04/04
A4042212    Gocini      2011/09/30  2013/09/29  2012/10/29
```

I want to group by EPPACC

Comment: What does the present code do? What is the problem with it?

Comment: The present code reads an excel file, extracts the information, displays it in netbeans and outputs it to another excel file (exactly the same data). There is no problem with it, i just dont know how to firstly group the data and then output each grouped part to a different excel sheet. For example a cellphone catalog, you want to group all the cellphone contracts for different phones, group them by phone and output each phone with all its contracts to different sheets.

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected grouping?

Comment: sure i can, i have edited the question with the data.

Comment: So you want every `EPPACC` go in a separate sheet?

Comment: ever     EPPACC that is the same on a different sheet

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at the grouping problem yet but would like to draw your attention at this statement.

```
file.close();
```

From the documentation of [`java.io.FileInputStream.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#close%28%29) this method:

> closes this file input stream and releases any system resources
>   associated with the stream. If this stream has an associated channel
>   then the channel is closed as well.

This could possibly be closing `XSSFWorkbook` instance `workbook` and making it unusable.

Comment: There's no problem with my outputs, it outputs to the file fine, my problem is defined in the to of the question and under your previous comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a separate Data collections for each group , assuming here based on `CELL_TYPE`

```
List<Boolean> myboolData;
List<Integer> myIntData;
List<String> myStrings;
```

And then based on the group selection from the data read, assign to purticular collection (i.e group)

```
switch(cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                myboolData.add(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                 myIntData.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                 myStrings.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Noted :) however this does not seems to help me resolve my true issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Working Solution.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Test {

    static ArrayList<XSSFWorkbook> grouplist = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame); // parentComponent must a component like JFrame, JDialog...
        File file = option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ? chooser.getSelectedFile() : null;

        try {
            if (file != null) {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

//Get the workbook instance for XLS file
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

//Get first sheet from the workbook
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

//Iterate through each rows from first sheet
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                Row header = rowIterator.next();//skiping columns header
                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Row row = rowIterator.next();
                    Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
                    String EPPACC = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    int i = validateGroup(header, cell.getStringCellValue());
                    XSSFWorkbook group = grouplist.get(i);
                    XSSFSheet sh = group.getSheet(EPPACC);
                    int rc = sh.getLastRowNum() + 1;
                    //creating a row
                    XSSFRow rowx = sh.createRow(rc);
                    for (Cell c : row) {
               //Creating cells
                        int cellType = c.getCellType();
                        XSSFCell cc = rowx.createCell(c.getColumnIndex(), cellType);
                        switch (cellType) {
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                cc.setCellValue(c.getBooleanCellValue());
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                cc.setCellValue(c.getNumericCellValue());
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                cc.setCellValue(c.getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                        }

                    }
                }
                fis.close();

                for (XSSFWorkbook book : grouplist) {
                    int lastRowNum = book.getSheetAt(0).getLastRowNum();
                    String name = book.getSheetAt(0).getSheetName();
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(file.getParentFile() + "/" + name + ".xlsx"));
                    book.write(out);
                    out.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static int validateGroup(Row header, String value) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < grouplist.size(); i++) {
            XSSFWorkbook group = grouplist.get(i);
            XSSFSheet sheet = group.getSheet(value);
            if (sheet != null) {
                //group exist.
                return i;
            }
        }
        //create a new book
        XSSFWorkbook group = new XSSFWorkbook();
        //create a new sheet
        XSSFSheet sheet = group.createSheet(value);
        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
        Iterator<Cell> iterator = header.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = iterator.next();
            XSSFCell c = row.createCell(cell.getColumnIndex(), cell.getCellType());
            c.setCellValue(cell.getStringCellValue());
        }
        grouplist.add(group);
        return grouplist.size() - 1;

    }

}
```